# How to install cryptsetup-luks

Tags: linux, rhel, encryption, luks

I'm actually trying to setup LUKS on a Red Hat 9.2 Server.

Here is the problem : I can't do `yum install cryptsetup-luks` or `dnf install cryptsetup-luks`.

When I try to use one of these command I have the following output :

```
no match for parameter: cryptsetup-luks
error: unable to find a match: cryptsetup-luks
```

I don't really understand why, because I'm following procedures from IBM and Official Red Hat documentation. The links of these procedures are below :

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/order-management-sw/10.0?topic=considerations-encrypting-data-partitions-using-luks

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/eng-eng/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/encrypting-block-devices-using-luks_security-hardening#options-for-data-protection-during-luks2-re-encryption_encrypting-block-devices-using-luks

I think the problem can comes from my repos because my repolist is as follow :

```
Local-AppStream
Local-BaseOS
Tuleap
epel
epel-cisco-openh264
remi-modular
remi-safe
```

Anyone can explain me what am I doing wrong ? Or if I didn't see an important thing ?

I tried to check if any other encryption solution was present on my system regarding which packages are installed that could be apparented to this. But even if I'm new on this activity, I didn't see any package that could be blocking me.

Thanks

Comment: is there a `cryptsetup` package? it does luks by default so it's usually implied

Comment: I will check it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is called just `cryptsetup`. It used to be called `cryptsetup-luks` way back in RHEL 6 but since RHEL 7 it's just `cryptsetup` and it's in the BaseOS repository so you don't need any other extra repository.

Comment: Oh thank you, IBM's documentation is therefore out of date :')